# find element in selenium by sub string

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, findelement

I am coding in java with selenium and i am stuck.
I have to find element by ID, the Id of the element is like this `"msi_num_create-copy"` (the num is changing every time), there is a way to find the element by part of the Id?

Comment: `//*[contains(@id, 'your_sub_string')]` , You also have the function `starts-with`, instead of `contains`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

yes you would need to use either css selector or xpath :

XPATH would be :

```
//*[contains(@id, '_create-copy') and starts-with(@id, 'msi')]
```

and use it like this :

```
WebElement someEle = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[contains(@id, '_create-copy') and starts-with(@id, 'msi')]"));
someEle.click(); or someEle.sendKeys("some string");
```